# What does 'unreserved' signify for a legal judgment?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p. 115.

> 6.72. *High Trees* is in many ways a weak precedent. The case is so influential and well known
>   that students often forget that it was a first instance decision, which was '***(remarkably)***' 
>   delivered **[unreserved](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unreserved)**, and that all the discussion about the binding nature of the promise
>   to reduce the rent during the war years was strictly obiter (described by Arden LJ
>   in *Collier v P&MJ Wright (Holdings) Ltd* (2007) as Denning J’s ‘brilliant obiter dictum’)

Ewan McKendrick. [*Contract Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2018 8 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Text-Cases-Materials/dp/019880816X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 217.

> #### Commentary
>
> Professor Treitel has stated (*Some Landmarks of Twentieth Century Contract Law* (Oxford
>   University Press, 2002), p. 29) that ‘the *High Trees* case is surely one of the most prominent of
>   the landmarks in twentieth century contract law’. He notes that its exalted status is, in many

p 218.

> ways, remarkable given that it was apparently argued and decided in one day. The judgment
>   of Denning J was therefore, in all probability, an **unreserved** judgment. As Professor Treitel
>   has remarked, ‘if there was any time for reflection, it could at most have been the luncheon
>   recess’. The facts of the case are rather unusual in that the litigation was conducted between
>   members of the same corporate group and it is not altogether clear why the claim was
>   brought in the first place. The claim may not in fact have been a ‘friendly’ one but a keenly
>   fought contest between the defendant and the creditors of the plaintiff company.

***(remarkably)*** implies that the author of the above quote was startled. So which definition fits? I quote [ODO's definitions of 'unreserved'](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unreserved).

> 1. Without reservations; complete
> 2. Frank and open
> 3. Not set apart for a particular purpose or booked in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this use of "unreserved" is very detailed legal jargon.  A judge or law professor in the appropriate jurisdiction would know the answer; very few non-lawyers (even with access to a comprehensive dictionary) would be able to determine the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unreserved* here is legal jargon, meaning that the judge did not "reserve judgment": put the case on hold for a while while he researched legal precedent and determined how a complex issue should be resolved.

The judge's discussion was "obiter"—that is, it was stated "by the way" as a matter of  his own opinion, not a part of the judgment itself, and hence not to be received as a precedent.